# Django South: How to use with multiple installs of codebase and one central database?

Tags: python, django, django-south

I am converting an existing codebase (with several apps) to use South. My codebase is currently installed on 1 development server and 3 production servers. The development has its own database and the 3 production servers are all connected to one central database.

I read the info at http://south.aeracode.org/docs/convertinganapp.html but I am still a bit confused as to how to proceed.

This is the steps I plan to follow:
`Dev Server: ./manage.py syncdb` (To create South tables in dev db)
`Dev Server: ./manage.py convert_to_south myapp` (To create South files & records in the dev db)
`Dev Server: push to VCS`

`Server 1: pull from VCS` (To get South files)
`Server 1: ./manage.py syncdb` (To create South tables in production db)
`Server 1: ./manage.py migrate myapp 0001 --fake` (To create South records in the production db)

`Server 2: pull from VCS (To get South files)`
`Server 2: ./manage.py migrate myapp 0001 --fake`

`Server 3: pull from VCS (To get South files)`
`Server 3: ./manage.py migrate myapp 0001 --fake`

Repeat these steps for all apps.

**Question 1:**
Is the `./manage.py migrate myapp 0001 --fake` step required on Servers 2 and 3? Since I will be running the migrations on Server 1 and all three servers are using the same database, it seems like it should not be required but I am not 100% sure.

**Question 2:**
If `./manage.py migrate myapp 0001 --fake` is required on Servers 2 and 3, will I need to run the command on Servers 2 and 3 every time I do a database migration?

As always, thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You use it only to apply changes to the database schema. You don't need to run migrate again on Servers 2 and 3, since they are using the same db as Server 1.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it. I suspected that the `--fake` command was not required on Servers 2 and 3, but I wasn't sure since the instructions on South's docs sort of implied they were.